# EnumWindow() to catch tab process (Google Chrome) C++

Tags: c++, winapi, process, window, pid

I'm using `EnumWindow()` function with `EnumWindowProc()` callback (definition [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/ms633498(v=vs.85).aspx)) to enum all applications running on my machine which have a window.
It works fine, but I can't see tab process. For example, if I have more than one tabs opened in Google Chrome (or Notepad++), `EnumWindow()` catches only the tab in focus, while the other tabs are not enumerated, even if Google Chrome uses different processes for each tab. There's a way to get them with this function? I'm trying to do that without process ID (I don't know how to get PID of process that are not listed with `EnumWindow()`), but any other hints are welcome.

Comment: It is for the obvious reason: they don't create a window.  Impossible to answer without knowing what you want to do to them.  Whatever you are contemplating, don't do it.

Comment: I just want to enumerate them. They don't create a window, but they belongs to the same window of the tab that EnumWindow() shows. I want to know if there's a way to simply enum the other tabs, having the tab which is in focus.

Comment: *"I'm using `EnumWindow()` [...] to enum all applications running on my machine"* - Wrong. The [EnumWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497.aspx) function enumerates top-level windows. Not processes. Your conclusions are wrong as well. It doesn't enumerate Chrome's current tab. It enumerates Chrome's top-level window, that changes its window title based on the currently selected tab. The tabs aren't windows. They're just a very convincing illusion. It's unlikely that you get helpful answers unless you produce a succinct problem statement.

Comment: Thank you. So to enum them I have to use their PID? I'm pretty new to this topic, sorry if my considerations sound stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every window you see is owned by the same Chrome process, so this just doesn't work.
What's separated into another process is the back-end code (Javascript, rendering, etc.).

On top of this, Chrome renders most if not all of the browser in the same Win32 "window" manually, so you won't be able to find its tabs separately through Windows API mechanisms.